# Develop with HTML and Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to develop entire dynamic website with only HTML and Javascript? I would like to use a Javascript HTML dynamic server. Is it exists?

Comment: What do you mean by a "dynamic server"?

Comment: please define what you mean by a "Javascript HTML dynamic server"

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what exactly that dynamic web site should do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Something like ASP.NET or JSP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. look into [Node](http://nodejs.org/), a Javascript on the server solution that lets you do things with javascript that is usually done in php, perl or c# (and friends).